# How to use mongodb projection query in array elements

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, pymongo

**I would like to project only "type":"A" in menu. is there a way to achieve this?**

```
    "_id" : "1",
    "menu" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "A",
            "items" : [ 
                {
                    "key" : "Add",
                    "enabled" : true,
                }            ]
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "B",
            "items" : [ 
                {
                    "key" : "Add",
                    "enabled" : true,
                }    ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want tou output only the menu which type is A you can use `$elemMatch` in a find query (take care because this only return the first matched element)

```
db.collection.find({},
{
  "menu": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "type": "A"
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4zimrSwXDyB)

Or `$filter` in an aggregate query (this returns all objects with `type: "A"` in the array):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "menu": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$menu",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$this.type",
              "A"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/J-B_EO0WlDF)